# How would I display a shape in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() in Processing?

Tags: java, swing, processing

Part of the requirement is to replicate the bar graph in https://i.stack.imgur.com/avmED.jpg

I tried this to see if I could rectangle in the dialogue window (obviously it didn't work):

```
rectMode(CENTER);

  // Alberta
  if ( prov_id.equals("AB") || prov_id.equals("ab"))
  {
    if (gross_income>=0&&gross_income<=40000)
    {
      tax_rate=0.25;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Province:    "+ prov_id + "\nGross Income:    "+ gross_income + "\nTax Rate:    "+ tax_rate+ "\nTax Amount:    "+ tax_amount+"\nNet Income:    "+ net_income + rect(10,10,10,10));

    }
```

The rest of my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


//Input Variables
String prov_id = "";                  //province_id will contain the user input for the province (E.g. 'AB'). 
float gross_income = 0;               //gorss_income contains the user input for gross income (E.g. 30000). 

//Output Variables:
//You will store the result of your analysis and calculations in these variables
float tax_rate = 0;                        //Variable tax_rate will hold the tax_rate percentage. You will assign a value for tax_rate based on the Taxable Income (Table 1) table given in the studio project document. 
                                           //The value of tax ranges between 0 to 1 (E.g. for Alberta, income of equal or less than $40000 tax = 0.25)

float net_income = 0;                     //Net income is calculated based on tax_rate. It is the take-home income after taxes are deducted. 
                                          //i.e. net_income = gross_income * (1 - tax_rate); 

float tax_amount = 0;                    //tax amount is the amount of taxes paid based on gross income depending on the province.
                                        //i.e. tax_amount = gross_income * tax_rate;

// prompt for and read the province id 
prov_id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your province's two-letter abbreviation (e.g., AB for Alberta): ");

// prompt for and read the gross income
String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your taxable income: ");

//convert user input to folat
gross_income = Float.parseFloat(answer);


net_income=gross_income*(1-tax_rate);
tax_amount=gross_income*tax_rate;
rectMode(CENTER);

  // Alberta
  if ( prov_id.equals("AB") || prov_id.equals("ab"))
  {
    if (gross_income>=0&&gross_income<=40000)
    {
      tax_rate=0.25;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Province:    "+ prov_id + "\nGross Income:    "+ gross_income + "\nTax Rate:    "+ tax_rate+ "\nTax Amount:    "+ tax_amount+"\nNet Income:    "+ net_income);

    }

  }
```

The expected out put is supposed to be this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/avmED.jpg

So far my code displays this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/avmED.jpg

Comment: Not a very detailed answer, but only a hint (and thus, only a comment): You can create an arbitrary component (e.g. a `JLabel` or a `JPanel`, with stuff like rectangles painted on it), and simply show it inside the dialog by calling `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, yourComponentWithStuffOnIt);`

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use Processing for this? That looks like pure Swing, not Processing. Alternatively, are you sure you have to show it in a message dialog?

Comment: I realized that most likely the window where the bar graphs are shown is Processing's not one from JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() since the window is named "TaxCalculator_kEY" not "Message".

Answer (score 0):

The window where the bar graphs are shown is Processing's not one from JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() since the window is named "TaxCalculator_kEY", which i assume is the name of the file, not "Message".